# Continue download if network adapter is changed

Tags: networking

If an application is downloading something, and I switch my network adapter, using the Unity indicator, the download stalls.

For example, if I am installing software using `apt`, and I activate the Wi-Fi adapter, and then I deactivate the wired Ethernet adapter, the package download stops.  Note that `apt` does not crash or terminate; it just stops processing if it needs to continue downloading packages, and I have to user CTRL-C to interrupt it.

This same issues happens if I am downloading something in Firefox or Chrome.

Is there a way to make running applications automatically switch to using the newly activated network adapter and continue the download(s)?

Comment: no packets are moving. different MAC address. impossible.

Comment: As Mark has already mentioned, it's impossible simply due to how networking operates and how packets are supposed to be routed. If you change interface, it means router no longer knows where to send the stuff and closes the connection.

Comment: Mark if you write this up as an answer, with a little more info about MAC addresses and why you can't switch the network interface for an established connection, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is called "roaming".
Here are two quite old Ubuntu pages about it, to give you an idea :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RoamingProfilesWithNetworkManager

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NetworkRoaming

I don't know what the current state of network roaming for NetworkManager is, but this at least gives you the keywords "network roaming" to search for.
Apart from this you can look at Download Managers like uget and wget.

Comment: Somehow I doubt that this is what OP wants. The summary on last link says: "Provide a better user experience when **connecting/disconnecting to/from various dynamically configured networks**" . OP's main issue is with different interfaces connecting to same network.